# We can't identify the issue with images on our blog (Could not load the image)

Tags: wordpress, image, responsive-design, responsive

We're using a WordPress theme and we're facing a problem with images on our blog. ***On mobile view*** (or tablet view...maybe more, I'm not sure), it's showing "*Could not load the image*" when preview it (I'm using firebug). But when we check it by put link of image into browser address bar that's working good (so it's not the problem with missing image). This seems to happen with some images (responsive design problem !?)

Here is a screenshot

[image]

You can check this on our homepage (mobile view): ohiwill.com (the first article on Latest Explore Posts section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are loaded in via a `srcset` which will load certain images based on device resolution.

You are missing some thumbnail sizes.

You can see this one (1023px wide screens) exists:

https://www.ohiwill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/legitimate-earn-money-online-1023x510.jpg

But the one loaded for sub 1000px wide screens does not: https://www.ohiwill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/legitimate-earn-money-online-1000x500.jpg

Either the 1000x500 size got deleted, didn't crunch properly, or for some reason that's not being registered as a valid thumbnail size and you can add it back in using [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

Comment: Yes. Good to know. Thank you so much. We have changed images size that's using `add_image_size()` (we want to use another size). If we change this then we will lose current changes of image size. How do we keep them and it's fixed for old image size ?.

Comment: Shall we change it (image sizes)by manually ? or how to regenerate images size ?

Comment: Unfortunately the 404 means it's physically been removed or renamed - but it should be trivial to manually make the 1000x500 one yourself, name it `legitimate-earn-money-online-1000x500.jpg` and put it in the `https://www.ohiwill.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/` directory

Comment: You can also make sure 1000x500 is a valid size and then use the [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin

Comment: Yes. I'm going to do that. I will find more images which getting this problem and fix them. Btw, do you know how to check which are the images get this problem ? I have just saw once of them. Thanks again !

Comment: My pleasure! Unfortunately, there's not a great way I can think of that would show you all of them. If I were you I'd manually add the one you found, make sure 1000x500 is a registered image size, and then run the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to force all thumbnail sizes to be recreated. A bit of a brute force fix, but we've had to do it before with corrupted images in a similar fashion. Good luck!

Comment: Yes. We have installed Regenerate Thumbnails plugin before but we have deactived it and i think that's getting this problem. Ok, thank you !